# NWjs: Chat head click not working if -webkit-app-region: drag is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit, node-webkit

I am trying to create a chat application that has chat head when the user is not chatting. On chat head click I want to open the list of chats.

[image]

**Problem**

In order to make chat heads draggable, I have set the `-webkit-app-region: drag`

The problem with `-webkit-app-region` is that if it is set then the mouse clicks are not working.

Please suggest what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documented solution for this however on the github I found a workaround

Source: [Git disussion thread](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3274#issuecomment-154343737)

Here is the workaround

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var wX = 0;
    var wY = 0;
    var dragging = false;
    $('#chatIcon').mousedown(function (e) {
        dragging = true;
        wX = e.pageX;
        wY = e.pageY;
    });

    $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (dragging) {
            var xLoc = e.screenX - wX;
            var yLoc = e.screenY - wY;


            try {
                window.moveTo(xLoc, yLoc);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

        }

    });

    $(window).mouseup(function () {
        dragging = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I will sugest to add a listener  $('#chatIcon').dblclick with document.documentElement.requestFullscreen(); to fully simulate the -webkit-app-region behaviour